# R: Create multiple new columns based upon other columns

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data-frame that looks like this

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "ID week1_t week1_a  week2_t week2_a
  1      12      22       17       4   
  1      15      32       18       5   
  1      24      12       29       6   
  2      45      11       19       8   
  2      23      33       20      10")
```

Is there a straightforward way to create a week1_d column, a week2_d column, and so on for every week, that is based on the difference between week1_t and week1_a?  Or do I have to manually construct the "difference" columns?

Expected output looks like this:

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "ID week1_t week1_a  week2_t week2_a week1_d week2_d 
  1      12      22       17       4       10       -13                 
  1      15      32       18       5       17       -13   
  1      24      12       29       6       -12      -23 
  2      45      11       19       8       -34      -11
  2      23      33       20      10       10       -10      ")
```

In actuality, there are around 30 weeks, so I am trying to avoid manually doing this.  I was thinking a for loop the runs through each week, and grepping columns that match week+(index of loop).  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a "tidy data" perspective, your problem is that you're encoding (multiple!) pieces of data in your column names: the week number and whatever the letter stands for. I would convert to a long format where week is a column, define `d = a - t`, and (if necessary) convert back to wide format. But probably I'd keep it in the long format because if there are any other operations you want to do they'll probably be easier to implement on the long data (more manipulation, modeling, plotting...).

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

long = dd %>% 
    mutate(real_id = 1:n()) %>%
    gather(key = key, value = value, starts_with("week")) %>%
    separate(key, into = c("week", "letter")) %>% 
    spread(key = letter, value = value) %>%
    mutate(d = a - t)

head(long)
#   ID real_id  week  a  t   d
# 1  1       1 week1 22 12  10
# 2  1       1 week2  4 17 -13
# 3  1       2 week1 32 15  17
# 4  1       2 week2  5 18 -13
# 5  1       3 week1 12 24 -12
# 6  1       3 week2  6 29 -23

wide = gather(long, key = letter, value = value, a, t, d) %>%
    mutate(key = paste(week, letter, sep = "_")) %>%
    select(-week, -letter) %>%
    spread(key = key, value = value)

wide
#   ID real_id week1_a week1_d week1_t week2_a week2_d week2_t
# 1  1       1      22      10      12       4     -13      17
# 2  1       2      32      17      15       5     -13      18
# 3  1       3      12     -12      24       6     -23      29
# 4  2       4      11     -34      45       8     -11      19
# 5  2       5      33      10      23      10     -10      20
```

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks a bunch, Gregor.

Comment: @Gregor great answer

Answer (score 3):

We `split` the 'week' columns (`dd[-1]`) by the `names` of the dataset after removing the suffix with `sub` into a `list`, get the difference between the two columns and assign the `list` elements to create new columns in 'dd'.

```
lst <-  lapply(split.default(dd[-1], 
           sub("_.*", "", names(dd)[-1])), function(x) x[2]-x[1])
dd[paste0("week_", seq_along(lst), "d")] <- lapply(lst, unlist, use.names=FALSE)
dd
#    ID week1_t week1_a week2_t week2_a week1_d week2_d
#1  1      12      22      17       4      10     -13
#2  1      15      32      18       5      17     -13
#3  1      24      12      29       6     -12     -23
#4  2      45      11      19       8     -34     -11
#5  2      23      33      20      10      10     -10
```

---

If the columns are alternating i.e. 'week1_t' followed by 'week1_a', then 'week2_t', followed by 'week2_a', etc.

```
Un1 <- unique(sub("_.*", "", names(dd)[-1]))
i1 <-  c(TRUE, FALSE)
dd[paste0(Un1, "_d")] <-  dd[-1][!i1]- dd[-1][i1]
dd
#  ID week1_t week1_a week2_t week2_a week1_d week2_d
#1  1      12      22      17       4      10     -13
#2  1      15      32      18       5      17     -13
#3  1      24      12      29       6     -12     -23
#4  2      45      11      19       8     -34     -11
#5  2      23      33      20      10      10     -10
```

Comment: @Parseltongue  It is updated.  Please check if that helps

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure exactly what the code is doing. What is that first split command's purpose?  I'm getting the following error: https://i.imgur.com/JDe1qYM.png

Comment: @Parseltongue  This is only based on the example you showed.  It works for me.  BTW, here I am using only `base R` functions.

Comment: Thanks for this, akrun.  I learned a lot of new functions.  I'm sure this works, it just happens to not work for me.  I've upvoted you in any case.

Comment: @Parseltongue  I updated with another simple solution.