# Convert column headers into new columns

Tags: r

My data frame consists of time series financial data from many public companies. I purposely set companies' weights as their column headers while cleaning the data, and I also calculated log returns for each of them in order to calculate weighted returns in the next step.

Here is an example. There are four companies: A, B, C and D, and their corresponding weights in the portfolio are 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1 separately. So the current data set looks like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(vector(),ncol=9, nrow = 4))
colnames(df1) <- c("Date","0.4","0.4.Log","0.3","0.3.Log","0.2","0.2.Log","0.1","0.1.Log")
df1[1,] <- c("2004-10-29","103.238","0","131.149","0","99.913","0","104.254","0")
df1[2,] <- c("2004-11-30","104.821","0.015","138.989","0.058","99.872","0.000","103.997","-0.002")
df1[3,] <- c("2004-12-31","105.141","0.003","137.266","-0.012","99.993","0.001","104.025","0.000")
df1[4,] <- c("2005-01-31","107.682","0.024","137.08","-0.001","99.782","-0.002","105.287","0.012")
df1
        Date     0.4 0.4.Log     0.3 0.3.Log    0.2 0.2.Log     0.1 0.1.Log
1 2004-10-29 103.238       0 131.149       0 99.913       0 104.254       0
2 2004-11-30 104.821   0.015 138.989   0.058 99.872   0.000 103.997  -0.002
3 2004-12-31 105.141   0.003 137.266  -0.012 99.993   0.001 104.025   0.000
4 2005-01-31 107.682   0.024  137.08  -0.001 99.782  -0.002 105.287   0.012
```

I want to create new columns that contain company weights so that I can calculate weighted returns in my next step:

```
        Date        0.4 0.4.W   0.4.Log     0.3 0.3.W   0.3.Log    0.2  0.2.W   0.2.Log     0.1 0.1.W   0.1.Log
1 2004-10-29    103.238 0.400   0.000   131.149 0.300   0.000   99.913  0.200   0.000   104.254 0.100   0.000
2 2004-11-30    104.821 0.400   0.015   138.989 0.300   0.058   99.872  0.200   0.000   103.997 0.100   -0.002
3 2004-12-31    105.141 0.400   0.003   137.266 0.300   -0.012  99.993  0.200   0.001   104.025 0.100   0.000
4 2005-01-31    107.682 0.400   0.024   137.080 0.300   -0.001  99.782  0.200   -0.002  105.287 0.100   0.012
```

Comment: Naming columns things starting with numbers is going to make your life a miserable mess of backticks.

Comment: And working in a wide data format is a miserable mess as well. This would be trivial if your data was in long format with one column for Date, one column for Weight, one column for Return, and one nicely named column for whatever the values in your `0.4`, `0.3`, ... columns in your result are.

Comment: [See my answer here from earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37865643/903061) for some nice conversions of wide into long, separating out variables that have misplaced inside column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
v1 <- grep("^[0-9.]+$", names(df1), value = TRUE)
df1[paste0(v1, ".w")] <- as.list(as.numeric(v1))
```