# How to eval multiple mutates in one R command?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 60 columns in a data.table called `x.b.0` and `x.a.0` with the 0 ranging from 0 to 59. I want to add 60 columns each of which is the corresponding difference between the .b and the .a entries. So, for example, I can get one such desired column like this:

```
require(magittr)
require(dplyr)
x %>% mutate(x.diff.16 = x.a.16 - x.b.16)
```

I tried getting this to work for all columns at once by doing this:

```
formulas = sapply(0:59, function(i) { paste0('x.a.',i,' = x.a.',i,' - x.b.',i,')')}) 
foo = paste(formulas, collapse=',')
x %>% mutate(eval(parse(text=foo)))
```

But this complains of unexpected ','. Is there a better way to do this or a workaround here?

Here is an example reduced table:

```
require(data.table) 
set.seed(17)
x = data.table(x.a.0 = rnorm(10), x.b.0=rnorm(10), x.a.1=rnorm(10), x.b.1=rnorm(10), x.a.2=rnorm(10), x.b.2=rnorm(10))
```

This is what I ended up doing:

```
x.mat = x %>% select(starts_with('x.')) %>% as.matrix()
k = ncol(x.mat / 2)
diff.mat = sapply(1:k, function(i) {v=c(rep(0,i-1),rep(0,k-i)); matrix(data=c(-v,v),ncol=k,byrow=TRUE)})
x.diff = x.mat %*% diff.mat
colnames(x.diff) = sapply(0:61, function(i) { paste0('x.n.',i)})
x = cbind(x, x.diff)
```

Comment: There's almost certainly a more graceful way using `mutate_each` that doesn't require `eval(parse(`, but it's hard to help with no data.

Comment: Really, this seems like a duplicate [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37865643/903061). The problem is that your data isn't tidy - you're encoding information into column names. If you melt your data into a long, tidy format that this would be a single mutate with `dplyr`.

Comment: How many rows do you have in your data?

Comment: I have about 40k rows, I've edited to include my current "solution" which relies on the ordering I have my columns in. I like Gregor's solution but need to familiarize myself with the package first.